# How do I add only the parameter value to the endpoint in camel?

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-http

```
<camel:from id="_from2" uri="timer://foo?repeatCount=1"/>
            <camel:to id="_to2" uri="DBSQLComponent:{{sql.testQuery}}"/>
            <log id="_log4" message="Received ${body.size()} records from the poller query"/>
            <log id="_log5" message="Message Body= ${body}"/>
            <to id="_to3" uri="log:output?showAll=true"/>
            <camel:process id="_processNewNotifications" ref="newNotifications"/>
            <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod" id="setHeader4">
                <constant>GET</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <setHeader headerName="Content-Type" id="_setHeader5">
                <constant>application/json</constant>
            </setHeader>                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpQuery" id="setHeader7">
                <simple>Id=${property.POList}</simple>
            </setHeader>
            <inOut id="_createPO" uri="cxfrs:bean:purchaseOrderDetailsEndpoint+${property.POList}"/>
</camel>
```

I am new to Camel and I am struggling to find resources to append only the value of the parameter? For the current code, it will add ?Id=${property.POList} to the endpoint. I only want the value ${property.POList} to be added to the rest endpoint. Please advise the best course of action to adding only a value to the endpoint in Spring DSL. Thank you!

Comment: Where are you setting the value of ${property.POList}? And am I correct in assuming you're trying to call the CXFRS endpoint as a client?

Comment: I am setting it in <camel:process id="_processNewNotifications" ref="newNotifications"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting a special header called "CamelHttpQuery" which, when the exchange is passed to the CXFRS component will add its contents to the CXF URL as a HTTP query (that's why you're seeing the ? sign being automatically added).

You could try using the header "CamelHttpPath" instead, which should set the resource path.

Answer (score 0):

you can try a [toD](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html) or [receipientList](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/recipientList-eip.html) which allows parameter input into the URI